# How can I conditionally prevent a form from submitting with server-side/code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, form-submit, onsubmit

When my "submit" (Save) button is clicked, one thing it does is verifies that the two "totals" vals match, and returns if they don't, fingerwagging the user with a red 'bad boy!' message:

```
message = new LiteralControl();
AddVerticalSpace();
Controls.Add(message);
decimal? paymentTot = TryConvertToDecimal(boxPaymentAmount.Text);
if ((null == paymentTot) || (paymentTot < 0))
{
    paymentTot = 0M;
}
decimal? grandTot = TryConvertToDecimal(boxGrandTotal.Text);
if ((null == grandTot) || (grandTot < 0))
{
    grandTot = 0M;
}
if (grandTot != paymentTot)
{
    AddVerticalSpace();
    message.Text = "<span style='color:red'>Total and Payment Total do not match; Please enter the same amount for both values and try again.</span>";
    return;
}
```

What I intend with the "return" is that the submit is aborted; yet, with the code above, the form is still submitted - it reverts to its initial appearance/state. How can I conditionally prevent this automatic submit behavior?

### UPDATE

This is for Tyree Jackson:

Here's the server-side save button. First, it is conditionally dynamically created and configured thus:

```
if (AnyCheckboxSelected())
{
    // Create Save button
    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    btnSave = new Button();
    btnSave.ID = "btnSave";
    btnSave.Text = "Save";
    btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(btnSave_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(btnSave);

    AddVerticalSpace();
}
```

...and here is the event handler:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LiteralControl message = null;
    try
    {
        fullAddressChosen = rbFullAddress.Checked;
        paymentToAnIndividualDropDownChosen = rbPaymentToIndividual.Checked;
        paymentToAVendorDropDownChosen = rbPaymentToVendor.Checked;

        message = new LiteralControl();
        AddVerticalSpace();
        Controls.Add(message);
        decimal? paymentTot = TryConvertToDecimal(boxPaymentAmount.Text);
        if ((null == paymentTot) || (paymentTot < 0))
        {
            paymentTot = 0M;
        }
        decimal? grandTot = TryConvertToDecimal(boxGrandTotal.Text);
        if ((null == grandTot) || (grandTot < 0))
        {
            grandTot = 0M;
        }
        if (grandTot != paymentTot)
        {
            AddVerticalSpace();
            message.Text = "<span style='color:red'>Total and Payment Total do not match; Please enter the same amount for both values and try again.</span>";
            return;
        }
        ConditionallyCreateList();
        SaveInputToList();
        listOfListItems = ReadFromList();
        message.Text = "Saving the data has been successful";

        // Re-visiblize any rows with vals
        if (RowContainsVals(3))
        {
            foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "table-row";
        }
        if (RowContainsVals(4))
        {
            foapalrow4.Style["display"] = "table-row";
        }
        if (RowContainsVals(5))
        {
            foapalrow5.Style["display"] = "table-row";
        }
        if (RowContainsVals(6))
        {
            foapalrow6.Style["display"] = "table-row";
        }

        AddVerticalSpace();

        //CreatePDFGenButton(); 
        GeneratePDFAndMsg();
        btnGeneratePDF.Visible = true;

        AddVerticalSpace();
        GenerateLegalNotice();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message.Text = String.Format("Exception occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Default.aspx source:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function validateData() {
            var payment = parseFloat(document.getElementById('boxPaymentAmount').value).toFixed(2);
            var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('boxGrandTotal').value).toFixed(2);
            if (payment == null) payment = 0;
            if (total == null) total = 0;
            if (payment == total) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('Total and Payment Total do not match. Please enter the same amount for both values and try again!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="boxPaymentAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="boxGrandTotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return validateData();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

And code for Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: do your stuff here...
    }

}
```

Comment: Great; I was just working on a similar tack/down a very similar road, but your code is "more better" than my initial stab at it. I still need to set the button disabled if the values don't match, though.

Comment: Using code like this "document.getElementById('boxPaymentAmount')" you will get the reference to Input on client side. From here you can do what ever you want.

Comment: Won't this work just as well:
var savebutton = $("[id$=btnSave]");
?

Comment: This looks similar to jQuery, however appropriate syntax would be something like this:
var savebutton = $("#btnSave");

If you don't already have reference to jQuery library, you can do it using following code on HTML side (Default.aspx):
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: No, that syntax doesn't work in my situation, because Sharepoint or ASP.NET prepends a lot of stuff before the ID I assign; thus, I have to use the "ends with" syntax (id$=).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about preventing a form from submitting in a web browser, you should use client side code (i.e. JavaScript) for that.  Even if there was a way to do it in code behind, it would just be translated into client side code.  Otherwise, the form will submit even if it retains the edited values.

Comment: I have to use server-side code to do the submit. I may have to "refactor" this, for example by disabling the button if the two vals don't match.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I'm curious.  How do you plan to trigger the submit in the browser from the server side without using some form of Javascript?  Ultimately, the browser does not understand c# and your code would have to be invoked over the wire.  Unless you are thinking of writing a plugin, extension or some sort of ActiveX component, I don't see how you will be able to use server side code to without some form of communication from the browser.

Comment: I use both C# and jQuery; IOW, I already am "trigger the submit in the browser from the server side "; I have some server-side code (such as the "Save"  submit button) and some jQuery (for between-submit code). I do this because there are server-side things I need to do in connection with the submit (generating a PDF using iTextSharp, etc.)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon can you post an example of your server side "Save" submit button?  I suspect that what you have is a server side event handler for the button being clicked on the client side.  But the very underlying mechanics that make that work would be either a postback or a callback from the client to the server over the wire, in which case that is the form being submitted in order for the server the handle the event.  Point is, in order for the server to know what is happening, some kind of submission **must** be made from the client to the server.  You may be able to *pre* submit via ajax

Comment: ... you may be able to *pre* submit via ajax, and validate the form prior to final submission, but then I would recommend going full ajax style and moving away from code behind.  Build submission service end points, and use javascript to make the calls.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Based on your updated question it does appear that you are using classic ASP.Net web forms.  Due to this the form will always submit in some fashion in order to invoke the btnSave_Click method.  You can either opt to turn on ViewState (a bad idea in general) in order to preserve the values on the form, re-render or bind the fields on the form to the incoming values so that they re-render with the current values, or switch to a more modern technology for building your application.

Comment: This ASP.NET, in the sense that is Sharepoint, but I don't think its' really what you'd call Web Forms. Switching is out of my purview (and my hands, for that matter).

Comment: @TyreeJackson actually, this can be achieved with dual-way communication between the client and the server (for example with SignalR), where the server sends the client commands in an independant language (JSON for example) so the client can do a Java-Script call.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Ah, sharepoint.  You should consider tagging your questions with that tag to make that clear.  Please disregard my answer then for your scenario.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I agree, which still requires a connection to be established from the client side.  Hence a submission must still be made to open the signalr call, which is what I was trying to communicate to the original author when I said "Ultimately, the browser does not understand c# and your code would have to be invoked over the wire."